# 11” Mid 2012 MacBook Air Display issue

Tags: display, graphics

My wife’s 11” MacBook Air Mid 2012:

[image]

has been having this display issue in the last 2 years or so: **the screen will segment itself into rectangles**, which are small, and are wider than they are tall:

[image]

These rectangles may represent what was on screen before, or be discolored, or moved from their original position, or contain completely unknown display data. There are also occasionally extra anomalies, such as vertical or horizontal lines and bars. **The computer then is unresponsive until a hard manual reboot.**

I can’t pinpoint any specific thing that triggers the problem, because it seems to happen during streaming, browsing the Internet, using normal applications like Microsoft apps, Adobe Lightroom.

I took it in to a local Apple specialist store, and based off of the pictures below and my description, in less than 5 min they diagnosed it as a GPU problem. My questions are:

- Are they right?
- Is there a fix?
- Worth it to get repaired?
- Better idea to get a new computer?

https://www.reddit.com/r/macbookrepair/comments/k6l0kw/macbook_air_11_mid_2012_display_problem/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf

Comment: Please describe in words what the problem is. Stack Exchange disfavors links, for without the linked info, the question (and any answers or comments) become far less useful...and links disappear and go dead. If you absolutely must have us look at a picture, you can include one in your question by returning to the composing box (choose "edit" below your question), and selecting the "moon and mountains" icon just above the box for text entry.

Comment: Just as a note: you should grey out the serial number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a perfect answer to all your questions but it might help you whatsoever.

---

> Are they right?

From what I can tell, this actually looks like a hardware problem. However, without opening the MacBook it is very unlikely to find the actual cause. You should still try the [different startup modes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255). `D` for hardware diagnose, `opt` `cmd` `p` `r` for NVRAM/PRAM reset.

---

> Is there a fix?

This really depends on what's broken. It could be a defective GPU, but it could also just be a broken connector cable.

- **iMacs** from that decade are known to have [GPU overheating issues](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/2011-27-imac-overheating-issues.2046953/) (my Dad experienced this as well).

To analyze this further you would have to take the computer apart and/or take it into a repair shop. If you think you can detect hardware problems yourself, I suggest following [this iFixit guide](https://de.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Air_11%22_Mid_2012) and open the MacBook yourself. For example, a broken cable could be detected by basically anyone, motherboard repairs are obviously for Pros, but in general [possible](https://www.youtube.com/user/rossmanngroup).

---

The last two questions are so close, I am going to answer them as one:

> Worth it to repair/get a new one?

This very much depends on how much the repair would cost and how happy your wife is with this machine.

But as a general advice I would actually look into buying a new MacBook, since 8 years for laptop is not a bad age, especially for a low-speced MacBook Air 11". Even the cheapest new MacBook Air from this fall will feel lightyears faster and actually seems to be a [pretty good package](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XpK9fM_HDM) as early [reviews](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MkrEMjPk24) indicate. However, if you want to get one of those shiny new M1 powered Macs, keep in mind that these are the first ARM processor Macs, so you might run into software compatibility issues, so always check that first!

---

More info about these new Macs: [MBP, MBA or MacMini?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkI7lgfjRPM); [Another Review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4g2nPY-VZc&t=741s), [A WIRED Review](https://www.wired.com/review/macbook-air-m1-2020/), [why you might not want to buys these new Macs](https://www.forbes.com/sites/patrickmoorhead/2020/11/21/apple-macbook-pro-13-m1-reviewwhy-you-might-want-to-pass/)